# How to include an require.js based script into Angular as component

Tags: javascript, angular, requirejs, xtext, ace-editor

I like to create an Angular component with an xtext editor based on the Ace editor.
You can find examples of the editor https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/330_web_support.html and https://xtext-demo.itemis.com/ .

The code to include this into an plain html with require.js looks like this:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "jquery": "webjars/jquery/<version>/jquery.min",
        "ace/ext/language_tools": "webjars/ace/<version>/src/ext-language_tools",
        "xtext/xtext-ace": "xtext/<version>/xtext-ace"
    }
});
require(["webjars/ace/<version>/src/ace"], function() {
    require(["xtext/xtext-ace"], function(xtext) {
        xtext.createEditor();
    });
});
```

Now I'm struggling how to include this into an Angular based component. I tried the following.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

import 'ace-builds/src/ace';
import 'ace-builds/src/ext-language_tools';
import xtext from 'xtext/xtext-ace';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-qml-editor',
  templateUrl: './qml-editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./qml-editor.component.css']
})
export class MyDslEditorComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() componentId: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('xtext', xtext);
    xtext.createEditor();
  }
}
```

When I compile my code I get something like...

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/ace-builds/src/ace.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../lib/lang' in '..my-dir..\node_modules\ace-builds\src'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ace-builds/src/ace.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../lib/oop' in '..my-dir..\node_modules\ace-builds\src'
```

It seems that require.js don't work correctly in the ace.js file. All local references are not correctly resolved.

[image: ace.js]

Also after hours of googling I can't find an solution. But many it is mainly an missing of my understanding how it should work.

Any help on this would be really appreciated.